# How to use my PCs internet connection for my mobile phone?

Tags: networking, internet, ad-hoc-network, gprs

I don't want to take a GPRS connection and want to use my PC's internet connection to access internet on my mobile phone. Is it possible? i have [samsung sgh e251](http://www.phonegg.com/Samsung/SGH-E251/Samsung-SGH-E251.html).

I have a Vista machine, but can install Linux if required.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, the Personal Area Networking (PAN) Bluetooth profile allows this. PAN basically gives you a LAN over Bluetooth, so software on your PC and on your phone can talk to each other as if they were on a LAN.

However, to actually use your PC's net connection on the phone, your phone (or more precisely, the apps on your phone that you want to provide with net access) must support using the PAN instead of directly connecting to the internet via GPRS/UMTS/WiFi etc.. Whether this is possible depends on the software you want to use on the phone, so I suppose it will be phone-specific.

Also, your PC will have to function as a router between its net connection and its PAN connection. Again, most PCs can do this (usually called "connection sharing"), but configuration will depend on your PC's OS.

In short, it's theoretically possible, but might be quite difficult to set up depending on the software involved. I don't know of any short way of accomplishing this.